# Phone Gap Cross Platform Apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I am new to the mobile development.  I am taking online classes and researching, but normally is it a requirement to have a backend database to store information for a mobile phone app or where is data normally handled with phone apps?  I'm thinking of even simple examples of storing phone call logs or task items for user retrieval.    Also authentication, when setting up logins, would this happen normally from a backend database or authentication server that the app creater needs to maintain?

THank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Typically back end data is stored in a database in a server as done in web apps. Then you will expose the data using an HTTP based service (e.g. ASP.NET Web API) so that its easy for JavaScript to communicate with the service.  data is commonly encoded as JSON transferring data between the service and your app. Now your mobile app will take data from the service and display in the UI and for updates data is send to the service and the service updates it to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that makes sense.  Is there a local database put on the phone often for connectivity issues or just the backend server database should be enough?

Comment: If you need offline feature for your app(means ur app needs the data even if there is no connectivity) , then you can have a local database setup. Checkout HTML5 local storage features: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage . This is supported by PhoneGap.